# keyboard input works fine except for KeyCode::KEY_ENTER

Tags: cocos2d-x, keyboard-events, enter

I came across the problem with keyboard event listener - all keys work fine except the Enter key.
Here's my code:

```
listener = EventListenerKeyboard::create();
    listener->onKeyPressed = CC_CALLBACK_2(PauseMenu::InputHandler, this);
    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
```

......

```
void PauseMenu::InputHandler(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_DOWN_ARROW:
        Next(); break;
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_UP_ARROW:
        Previous(); break;
    case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_ENTER:
        Select(); break;
    }
}
```

I've tried to set different keys for needed action and they work fine. Could anyone explain what could be the reason of this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the ENTER key is the one on the numpad (lower-right corner of most keyboards), the RETURN key is the one above the RIGHT-SHIFT key and is perhaps what you are looking for instead.

The ENTER and RETURN keys typically are assigned different keycodes in game engines. Check if there's a `KEY_RETURN` type and try it with that.

Comment: Thank you, it turned out that the problem was with the code as you said.  For those who'll have the same problem, the needed code is 35 or KeyCode::KEY_KP_ENTER.